# iphone Xcode project files encrypt

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to send the project files to my client for running it on thier xcode to see the work in progress. Is there any way to encrypt the source files ? 
I have one option by sending .app file from simulator debug location and ask them to put it on the same path . But i need to send the code with encryption , is that possible ?

Thanks in Advance.
Raj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can encrypt the files via any number of mechanisms, but if you want the client to be able to build and run the code, that's not going to be practical, as they'd have to decrypt it.

If you want to do this without exposing the source code to the client, build a static library, distribute that static library which links along with a template main.m into your final executable, set it up as a framework to link into the sample app you send them. This way, they don't get the sources to the app, but they can still build it and see what's going on.

On a side note, if you don't trust your client, why did you take the job in the first place?