# how to encrypt my source code and export for developers in cocoa touch/xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

i wrote my persoal cocoa touch codes , i want get my sources(small framework) to my friends for use  , but i dont want anyone can read this my source code and changed it.

how to code or encrypt my Codes ?

Comment: Please clarify your question, Ehsan: do you want to share a framework (i.e. only a compiled library) or do you want to share a small set of source (which builds the small framework) with your friends?

Comment: It doesn't sound like they're really your friends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone Xcode project files encrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724314/iphone-xcode-project-files-encrypt)

Comment: my question mean : ANYONE CAN'T READ MY SOURCE CODE , I WANT PUBLISH IT CLOSE SOURCE not OPEN SOURCE, if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Publish to github and make it a private repo.  send invites to only your friends.

If it's small, you could compress w/ a password and then share the password w/ your friends.  But w/ the version control approach, you get obvious advantages.

Answer (score 1):

You could package your code into a static library.  Then you could give out only the compiled lib and the public interface headers.